# Find relation from localdatastore - Parse.com - Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore

I wrote a query to find all “parse objects” of type “categories” and “subcategories”. And pinned it in localdatastore in android.
I had Subcategories for some category as “Relation”.
I am unable to retrive it from localdatastore.

Suggest any idea to fetch “relation” from localdatastore.
Thanks in advance.

Tried “getRelation(key)” method  (which works fine when query against parse online).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264112/parse-how-can-i-get-relation-from-a-local-data-store-fromlocaldatastore