# Local data storage does not work as it should

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-storage

Because it does not work with all objects that have saved on my local Data storage?

If I remove the "fromLocalDatastore ()" it works.

Does anyone know any solution for this?

```
Midia midia = noticia.getImagem().getQuery().fromLocalDatastore().getFirst();
```

Image which confirms that the objects are saved in DataStorage site, including including the files:

[image]

Comment: please show how you save the objects to the local datastore

Comment: @cYrixmorten please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264112/parse-how-can-i-get-relation-from-a-local-data-store-fromlocaldatastore?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the problem is that local datastore does not support files at this moment (not sure but as I recall it does not). What you could do is

1. query the parse.com database
2. store the image on either internal or external storage, perhaps using the objectId as the name
3. now you can query the local datastore and easily locate the stored image using the objectId of the retrieved objects

Alternatively the images can be stored as a byte array as this blog suggests: http://www.cumulations.com/blogs/8/Problem-with-ParseFile-in-offline-mode

Comment: The parse can store files by byte arrays, checking the storage place I can confirm this. I will update the post with a database of print.